# How to Multiple using =LEN

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that counts the individual letters/numbers/symbols in a particular cell.

A2 = `LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,C$1,""))`

Counting anything from A-Z, 0-9 and "-" which is then totaled using auto sum.

I want to ad a column where the number entered will multiple the total in the formula above.

I'm not sure where to add the multiplication to the formula?

[image: Data Sheet]

I'm not sure where to add the multiplication to the formula?

Comment: Put brackets around the current formula and then multiply?

Comment: Although that sounds like a simple answer for most, I'm lucky to get as far as I have. Do you have an example?

Comment: `=(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,C$1,""))) * $B2`

Comment: Why the substitute? Len() counts all characters.

Comment: 'Multiply' in Excel formula is done using the `*` sign, so for example `=A2*B2` would give you A2 multiplied by B2.

Comment: Just FYI, if this is some older Excel version, you could do this in a single sweep: `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-",ROW($1:$37),1),)))`. Is that what you are after?